# How do these results prove my method is running in O(n lgn) time?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, runtime, big-o

I have a method that I wrote below.

```
public static long nlgn(double[] nums)  {

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        if(nums.length > 1)     {
            int elementsInA1 = nums.length/2;
            int elementsInA2 = nums.length - elementsInA1;
            double[] arr1 = new double[elementsInA1];
            double[] arr2 = new double[elementsInA2];

            for(int i = 0; i < elementsInA1; i++)
            arr1[i] = nums[i];

            for(int i = elementsInA1; i < elementsInA1 + elementsInA2; i++)
            arr2[i - elementsInA1] = nums[i];

            nlgn(arr1);
            nlgn(arr2);

            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

            while(arr1.length != j && arr2.length != k) {
                if(arr1[j] <= arr2[k]) {
                    nums[i] = arr1[j];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else {
                    nums[i] = arr2[k];
                    i++;
                    k++;
                }
            }

            while(arr1.length != j) {
                nums[i] = arr1[j];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            while(arr2.length != k) {
                nums[i] = arr2[k];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }

        double max = nums[nums.length - 1];
        double min = nums[0];

        double[] farthestPair = {max, min};

        long end = System.nanoTime();

        return (end - start);
    }
```

This is basically a merge sort operation that, once sorted, will find the smallest and largest numbers.  I believe this method is operating in O(n lgn) time.  However, when I run the function with an input size that doubles upon each run (1000, 2000, 4000, etc.), I get the following results when I time it in nano time.

```
First pass: (0.12) seconds
Second pass: (0.98) seconds
Third pass: (0.91) seconds
Fourth pass: (0.90) seconds
Fifth pass: (1.33) seconds
```

My question is, given these results, do these results suggest that this method is running in O(n lgn) time?

Comment: True, ok I think my wording was a bit off.  That is correct that I cannot prove it unless by logic.  I changed the wording of my question a bit.  Basically, I know if it takes roughly double the running time for double the input, that suggests the method runs in linear time.  With the results that I have, do they suggest that my method is running in O(n lgn) time?

Comment: As I said before, a runtime of 0.12 seconds is far too short to conclude anything about. Increase your benchmark size/repeats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the big-O complexity of this algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716582/what-is-the-big-o-complexity-of-this-algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the source code of the algorithm, you should analyze it instead of doing runtime benchmarks.

In the case of recursive functions, take a look to the **[master theorem](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/master.pdf)**.

In your function you do 2 recursive calls with size `n / 2`, so `a = 2, b = 2` and `f(n) = 2n`, because in your two first for loops you iterate along all the array (n) and with the three final while loops you iterate again all the array size (n), so `2n`.

If you apply the master theorem it gives you as result `Θ(n ln(n))`, so `O(n ln(n))` is correct too.