# What is the big-O complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, sorting, big-o

I have a function that I wrote below.  This function is essentially a merge-sort.

```
public static long nlgn(double[] nums)  {

        if(nums.length > 1)     {
            int elementsInA1 = nums.length/2;
            int elementsInA2 = nums.length - elementsInA1;
            double[] arr1 = new double[elementsInA1];
            double[] arr2 = new double[elementsInA2];

            for(int i = 0; i < elementsInA1; i++)
            arr1[i] = nums[i];

            for(int i = elementsInA1; i < elementsInA1 + elementsInA2; i++)
            arr2[i - elementsInA1] = nums[i];

            nlgn(arr1);
            nlgn(arr2);

            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

            while(arr1.length != j && arr2.length != k) {
                if(arr1[j] <= arr2[k]) {
                    nums[i] = arr1[j];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else {
                    nums[i] = arr2[k];
                    i++;
                    k++;
                }
            }

            while(arr1.length != j) {
                nums[i] = arr1[j];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            while(arr2.length != k) {
                nums[i] = arr2[k];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }

        return nuts;
    }
```

Since this is a merge sort, I know from my research that the big-O complexity of this algorithm is O(n lgn).  However, when I run my timing tests, the results I get do not suggest that this is running in O(n lgn) time.  It seems like it is O(n lgn) time though, because up until we get to the end of the two for loops at the beginning. it runs in O(n) time.  Once past that, it should be running in O(lgn) time as it sorts each element.

My question is, can somebody confirm that this piece of code is running in O(n lgn) time?  If not, I would like to know where I am going wrong in my understanding.

Comment: Reaaally similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716270/how-do-these-results-prove-my-method-is-running-in-on-lgn-time.

Comment: If you find problem solved, please do not forget to accept!

Comment: What results _did_ you get, and how do they suggest other than `O(n lgn)`? (Ignore any sub-second results, increase problem size.) If `O(lgn) time` is not a typing error, could you please argue in favour of this result?

Comment: (Nits: where do nuts come from? If you used `if (nums.length <= 1) return nums;`, there'd be one level of indentation less. `for(int i = elementsInA1; i < elementsInA1 + elementsInA2; i++) arr2[i - elementsInA1] = nums[i];` looks more complicated than `for (int i = 0 ; i < elementsInA2 ; i++) arr2[i] = nums[elementsInA1 + i];`.) (Erroneous comment on _space_ complexity removed - my bad.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since this is a merge sort, I know from my research that the big-O complexity of this algorithm is `O(n lgn)`. [...] My question is, can somebody confirm that this piece of code is running in `O(n lgn)` time?

No need to show it, because merge sort has already been *proven* to run in `O(n lg(n))` time. But if you'd like to observe it, you'll need to experiment with increasingly large values for your inputs. You might want to update your post with your input values and timing results.

> However, when I run my timing tests, the results I get do not suggest that this is running in `O(n lgn)` time. [...] If not, I would like to know where I am going wrong in my understanding.

I think you may be misunderstanding what Big-Oh notation actually tries to tell you. Big-O gives you an *approximation* of the asymptotic *upper bound* of the algorithm as the inputs become large enough. (How "large" is "large enough" will vary from algorithm to algorithm and would need to be found by experimentation. The point is that this value *does* exist and we represent it more abstractly.)

In other words, Big-O tells you what the *worst* case performance of the algorithm *could* be as `N` becomes very large. Since this is the *worst case scenario*, it also means that, it could perform better under some circumstances, but we don't generally care about those. (Look into Big-Omega and Big-Theta if you're interested.) For example, if you have a "small-enough" list, merge-sort can run faster than quick-sort and this is often used as an optimization.

It's also an approximation because the constants and other polynomial terms are *not* shown as part of the notation. For example, some hypothetical algorithm with a time complexity of `500x^2 + 15x + 9000` is going to be written as `O(n^2)`.

Some reasons for dropping the lower terms include:

- **Relative Size:** As `n` tends towards positive infinity, the larger `n^2` term *dominates*; the lower terms contribute less and less to the overall cost *in comparison to* the largest/dominating term --like adding a few drops or buckets of water into a lake;
- **Convenience:** Reading and understanding `O(n^2)` is easier than a long and more complicated polynomial for no real benefit

Answer (score 3):

O(nlogn) is an asymptotically tight bound. That means, only when n is large enough, its running time is close to the complexity. When n is small, because of function call overhead and many other factors, the bound is not tight.

You can make n larger, and compare the ratios between inputs to see if it is close to O(nlogn). Although I really doubt how large you have to make n to be...

Comment: Thank you for this info, this is helpful.  Can you explain what you mean by how you really doubt how large n has to be?

Comment: Well, because by the definition of asymptotic notation, say, T(n) = theta(nlogn). This means for any n larger than a constant n0, there exist  constant c1 and c2 such that  c1 nlogn <=T(n) <=  c2nlogn. Note that here n0 is an abstraction in mathematics, because we just say exists an n0, but we don't know how large it should be to make the approximation really as close as you want.